# React Native: View Config not found for name RNCWebView

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3NXP.png)

I'm trying to use WebView from react-native-webview so when i press the button (renderItem function) 
it'll open a webview from the link given by the api, but however i try to use the webview the error from the image appears.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api';

import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "JSHunt"
    };

    state = {
      productInfo: {},
      docs: [],
      page: 1,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.loadProducts();
    }

    loadProducts = async (page = 1) => {
      const response = await api.get(`/products?page=${page}`);

      const { docs, ...productInfo } = response.data;

      this.setState({ 
        docs: [... this.state.docs, ...docs], 
        productInfo,
        page
      });
    };

    loadMore = () => {
      const { page, productInfo } = this.state;

      if(page === productInfo.pages) return;

      const pageNumber = page + 1;

      this.loadProducts(pageNumber)
    };

    renderItem = ({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.productContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.productDescription}>{item.description}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.productButton}
         onPress={() => {
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Product', { product: item })
         }}>
          <Text style={styles.productButtonText}>Acessar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )

    render() {
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
            data={this.state.docs} keyExtractor={item => item._id} renderItem={this.renderItem}
            onEndReached={this.loadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}/>
          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

WebView component, here i'm using the arrow function instead of the class so i can pass the "navigation" data from the api that's being imported from '../services/api';

```
import React from 'react';

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

 const Product = ({ navigation }) => (
  <WebView source={{ uri: navigation.state.params.product.url}} />
);

Product.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: navigation.state.params.product.title
});

export default Product;
```

Comment: Same issue on iOS. I've tried 8.0.1 and 7.6.0.

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with how React Native is linking react-native-webview. Sometimes running `react-native link react-native-webview` will solve the problem. But sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it will say it's successful but still doesn't do the link properly

If the link command did not work, you must link manually

You'll need to manually change 3 files in the android folder.

1. **settings.gradle**

   rootProject.name = 'example'
   include ':react-native-webview'
   project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')

   include ':app'
2. **app/build.gradle**

   `dependencies {
   implementation project(':react-native-webview')
   implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
   implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From 
   node_modules
   }`
3. **app/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java**

a. Add this import `import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;`

b. Make sure the getPackages() function looks like this

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new RNCWebViewPackage()
  );
}
```

Rebuild your application and it should work.

Full tutorial for [IOS Here](https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-ae6c017a6b4a)
Full tutorial for [Android Here](https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-964399ec731b)

Answer (score 0):

Open iOS pod file -> add the react-native-webview reference to the pod